# How to change the file path of smarty html to be fetch?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, codeigniter-3, smarty3

Here's my problem, I setup Codeigniter (v.3) with the use of third party (MX thingy), now I tried to integrated the Smarty (v.3) (template) with the system. Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded the latest Smarty files from smarty.net
2. Edit the autoload.php

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('smarty');
   ```
3. copy the smarty files and pasted it on the application/libaries/Smarty
4. created a file smarty.php on application/libraries

   ```
       <?php
   if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   require_once( APPPATH.'libraries/Smarty/Smarty.class.php' );

   class CI_Smarty extends Smarty {
   public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();

           $this->compile_dir =  APPPATH. "templates_c";
           $this->template_dir = VIEWPATH ;
           $this->plugins_dir = APPPATH.'libraries/smarty/plugins/';
           $this->assign( 'APPPATH', APPPATH );
           $this->assign( 'BASEPATH', BASEPATH );

           // Assign CodeIgniter object by reference to CI
           if ( method_exists( $this, 'assignByRef') )
           {
               $ci =& get_instance();
               $this->assignByRef("ci", $ci);
           }

           log_message('debug', "Smarty Class Initialized");
       }
   function view($template, $data = array(), $return = FALSE)
       {
           foreach ($data as $key => $val)
           {
               $this->assign($key, $val);
           }

           if ($return == FALSE)
           {
               $CI =& get_instance();
               if (method_exists( $CI->output, 'set_output' ))
               {
                   $CI->output->set_output( $this->fetch($template) );
               }
               else
               {
                   $CI->output->final_output = $this->fetch($template);
               }
               return;
           }
           else
           {
               return $this->fetch($template);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. The files and folder structure of the skin folder are these:

   - skin
   - '->Theme
   - '-->Welcome
   - '--->files (welcome_message.html)
6. My code in the welcome conteroller (application\modules\welcome\welcome.php)

   ```
   class Welcome extends MX_Controller {

       function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->model('welcome_model','welcome');
       }
       public function index()
       {
           $this->smarty->display('welcome_message.html');
       }
   }
   ```
7. Now I try to Run it, but I got this error message:

   ```
       An uncaught Exception was encountered

       Type: SmartyException

       Message: Unable to load template file 'welcome_message.html'

       Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\cleanci01\application\libraries\Smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php

       Line Number: 139

       Backtrace:

       File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cleanci01\application\libraries\Smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
       Line: 192
       Function: render

       File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cleanci01\application\libraries\Smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
       Line: 109
       Function: _execute

       File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cleanci01\application\modules\welcome\Welcome.php
       Line: 14
       Function: display

       File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cleanci01\index.php
       Line: 294
       Function: require_once
   ```

I'm Not sure how will I tell smarty that he should get the file from "skin/theme/welcome/" and not in the FCPATH([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGWlm.jpg)). How can this possibly happen?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks guys!